# Regex capture in : and @

Tags: regex

I want regex for capture the values in `:` and `@`, help me please!!

**REGEX**

```
:(.+)@
```

**VALUES**

```
information:TH@THinformation@information
information:information:UD@UDinformation@information
```

**OUTPUT**

```
TH@THinformation
information:UD@UDinformation
```

**DESERIED OUTPUT**

```
TH
UD
```

[**REGEX101**](https://regex101.com/r/xsKiPD/1)

Comment: Use `:([^:@]+)@`

Comment: ohhh, great, thanks!!!